# Oracle Apex to receive form submit POST data

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am new to Oracle Apex.I am trying to receive POST data in Oracle Apex page. I want to submit a HTML form and receive that post submission in my Oracle Apex app. searched web but couldn't get suggestions.
In my Oracle database 11g, I have configured Apex 18.1 which is running in 8085 port and created some basic pages.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form action="http://localhost:8085/apex/f?p=106:4:9735956410807:::::" method="post">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to Oracle Apex page.".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

This POST submission will be from external source and Apex app should process this submission.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you expecting APEX to do with the POSTed information?

Comment: @EJEgyed Need to get a parameter value from that POST submission and redirect to another external URL with that value.

Comment: The easiest is to do the POST request in pl/sql using the API ```APEX_WEB_SERVICE```

Comment: @KoenLostrie what you suggest would be a outbound request from Apex. I want to process an inbound POST request to APEX. This POST request is submitted from external source.

Comment: You say you're new to APEX... APEX is all about creating html pages. The POST process is handled by the apex engine automatically. Why would you want to manually create an html page and post to apex instead of just creating the page in APEX ?

Comment: Embedding an apex page in an iframe on the external source - is that an option ? You could also create a restful service of method POST in ORDS (you can do this from within the apex builder) and redirect to the apex app after you have processed the request.

Comment: This is weird because you can create a form inside APEX but if you want to insert in database from another source you can use JDBC connection or a web service but this are you trying to do is not correct.

Comment: @KoenLostrie Thanks very much for your suggestion! I have done what you said, Created  a restful service  of method PSOT in ORDS and processed that redirect response.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options here:

1. You could create a webservice using APEX Restful services and sending there. It's probably much safer than exposing you application like you are doing. Worst case scenario you'll have to convert you form post to a json on the backend of the original app, which should be easy pease.
2. Why not just create a public page with an APEX form and execute a process after the submit happens? You have a tool that generate forms and you are building one from scratch?

*** Having said that, you might want to have the page in a different domain, site, etc... I still think you would be better telling on the other site that the person would be redirected and then sending it to the APEX form